# JavaFX - ScrollPane within GridPane

Tags: javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

I want a ScrollPane in my application window which doesn't fill the whole scene, but only takes up part of it, because I want to place a button beneath it.

Like in this sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxizX.png

I tried using a GridPane, but I can only put Nodes as children of the GridPane, which doesn't work because the ScrollPane is not a Node.

```java
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    var root = new GridPane();
    var scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    var scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    root.add(scrollPane, 0, 0); // Not possible

    var button = new Button();
    root.add(button, 0, 1);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: [`javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#contentProperty) definitely is a `javafx.scene.Node`. The class hierarchy is: `ScrollPane` → `Control` → `Region` → `Parent` → `Node`. There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown us; if you're having problems please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @Slaw: Damn you're right, I probably messed up the imports. Embarassing. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slaw's comment: 
javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane definitely is a javafx.scene.Node. The class hierarchy is: ScrollPane → Control → Region → Parent → Node